# CCC BarChart - how to set a fixed value for Y axis dynamically?

Tags: charts, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-ctools

I'm using Pentaho's Community dashboard editor.I'm using barchart.

I need to assign the fixed value for y axis dynamically according to result set.

In pre execution:

```
function(){
this.chartDefinition.orthoFixedMax = 10;
}
```

but result set are only shown in `post execution.`
how can I set fixed value for y axis dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used post fetch:

```
  function() {        
    var abc = render_LeadTimeLine.query.lastResults().resultset;
    //check result set & use 
    this.chartDefinition.orthoFixedMax = 10;

   }
```

Comment: this.chartDefinition.orthoAxisFixedMax = 10;